# Errors were encountered while processing: linux-image-extra-3.5.0-34-generic linux-image-generic linux-generic

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am having an issue with installing anything (via `apt-get`)  on an ubuntu 12.10 server (terminal only). Does anyone have any resources that could lead t a solution to the following error?

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.5.0-34-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
```

Comment: Could you add the lines before that?